# Grunt Sass Error: File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs

This works locally but when I grunt on my ubuntu I  get this sass error. I have ruby and sass installed, grunt as well

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: /public/libs/bootswatch-scss/cyborg/variables.
       Load path: /opt/app/soundapp/public/style/sass
        on line 1 of public/style/sass/style.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
File "public/builds/style.css" created.
```

As the error shows I use grunt to run my stuff. Here's the top of my style.scss

```
@import "public/libs/bootswatch-scss/cyborg/variables";
@import "public/libs/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
@import "public/libs/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "public/libs/bootswatch-scss/cyborg/bootswatch";
```

Here is my grunt file

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    jsFiles = [
        'public/libs/underscore/underscore.js',
        'public/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'public/libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
        'public/libs/jquery-ui/ui/core.js',
        'public/libs/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js',
        'public/libs/angular/angular.js',
        'public/libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'public/libs/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        'public/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
        'public/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'public/libs/restangular/dist/restangular.js',

        'public/js/services/**/*.js',
        'public/js/filters/**/*.js',
        'public/js/directives/**/*.js'
    ],
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    loadPath: [
                        'public/libs/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/',
                        'public/libs/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/',
                        'public/libs/font-awesome/scss',
                        'public/libs/bootswatch-scss/cyborg/'
                    ],
                    style: 'compressed'
                },
                files: {
                    'public/builds/style.css': 'public/style/sass/style.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
            },
            build: {
                src: 'builds/script.js',
                dest: 'builds/script.min.js'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        },
        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: ';',
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
            },
            dist: {
                src: jsFiles,
                dest: 'public/builds/script.js'
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            all: ['public/js/**/*.js']
        },
        notify_hooks: {
            options: {
                enabled: true,
                max_jshint_notifications: 5
            }
        },
        notify: {
            complete: {
                options: {
                    message: 'Grunt Completed!'
                }
            },
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['jshint', 'sass', 'concat', 'notify:complete']);
}
```

How can I begin to debug this? All the files in my public/libs/ exist so it has to be a compiling issue not related to it finding the files? I have Sass 3.4.13 and ruby 1.9.3p484 installed

Comment: Are you using the latest version of this module? https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-sass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax appears to be from an older version and may not still be supported or compatible,

```
sass: {
    dist: {
       options: {
           loadPath: [ ],
           style: 'compressed'
       },
       files: { }
    }
},
```

### but for grunt-contrib-sass v0.9.2

If you are importing all of your sass files into one main SASS file. You shouldn't have to define all of the *SASS import* paths in your grunt file. According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-sass) you could compile by just providing the path to your `.scss` file and you `.css` file and define the import paths in your main SASS file.

**For example:**

***in your style.scss assuming your directory structure is***

```
|--- style.scss
|--- public
      |--- libs
         |--- bootswatch-scss

      ...ect
```

***you would have something like this in your style.scss file***

```
@import "public/libs/bootswatch-scss/cyborg/variables";
@import "public/libs/bootswatch-scss/cyborg/bootswatch";
```

***and your grunt file like so***

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: {
        'public/builds/style.css': 'public/style/sass/style.scss'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Your comment was correct about my version of grunt contrib sass. IF you want to update your answer to that I 'll check mark it. My version was out of date and updating it did it for me.

Comment: So are you now on v0.9.2?

Comment: Answer updated.. I left the other info as well. Might be helpful for future users.